# Git / SourceTree - remote invalid username or password

Tags: git, passwords, push, atlassian-sourcetree

I've just reinstalled SourceTree on my new computer and I'm having trouble when trying to push my commits.

If I use the built-in Push button from SourceTree, it brings up a dialog where I enter my username and password but then I get an error: `remote invalid username or password`.

The strangest thing is that if I bring the Git console by clicking on the Console button in SourceTree, type `git push` then enter the exact same credentials, it works...

I'm assuming SourceTree might be overriding some Git config somehow but I can't find a solution.

I tried deleting all credentials saved by SourceTree, I disallowed SourceTree to modify my Git config in the Tools > General menu but it didn't change anything...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: On Mac, Got SourceTree-->Preferences-->Advanced -->Remove username for which its not working. Now try again it should work.

Answer (score 16):

If you are using SourceTree on Mac then go to SourceTree -> Preference -> Network

You will get the list of username for Remote URLs. You can update username there and next push/pull event that username will start getting reflect.

Comment: On Windows it is Tools - Options - Authentication

Comment: Just FYI I had to remove my host / username from SourceTree's Preference -> Network on macOS Sierra (SourceTree v. 2.5.3).  Then, when pulling new changes it prompted me for a new username / password.

Comment: on mac it doesn't seem to have a network option on preferences any longer

Answer (score 2):

I had two factor authentication on, so I needed to create new Personal access token in github.com settings page and use it as my password.

Answer (score 2):

SourceTree -> Preference --> accounts you can delete and add your account again and then try SourceTree -> Preference set Protocol = HTTPS

Answer (score 1):

Happend to me on SourceTree for Mac.

Username from `SourceTree -> Preference -> Accounts` and `SourceTree -> Preference -> Network` need to be aligned.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows you might try to remove OR edit the `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Atlassian\SourceTree\passwd` file. Edit means removing only the lines which correspond to the failed credentials

Answer (score 0):

`SourceTree` on Mac then go to `SourceTree -> Preference -> Network`. 
You'll see your username and GitHub location. Remove it.
Next, when you `push` to your `repo`, you'll be prompted for `username` and `password` (to save to chain).

Ideally, there was a `password` field here.

Answer (score 0):

One possible answer to this problem is to update your local version of git or update your embedded version of git. Newer versions of sourcetree do not play nice with older versions of git.

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/SourceTree-2-1-10-0-Authentication-Issues/qaq-p/623202

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this on `SourceTree 3.1.1` by going to `Preferences->Account->Edit->Connect Account`.